# p:selectOneMenu não atualiza valor dentro de ui:repeat

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

O contexto é o seguinte, tenho uma lista de objetos `AvaliaProjeto`, que contém:

- Projeto
- Criterio
- Escala
- Valor

O projeto é selecionado por fora, os critérios são listados para que sejam escolhidas suas escalas. Ou seja, cada objeto `AvaliaProjeto` contém uma relação entre escala e critério.

Criei esse diálogo para cadastro de `AvaliaProjeto` (que na realidade é uma sequência de avaliações), porém, listo os critérios e suas potenciais escalas via `ui:repeat`. O problema é que na hora de cadastrar, os atributos `Escala` estão nulos.

Seguem abaixo POJO, View e Print do diálogo.

#### VIEW

```
<table id="table">
    <tr>
        <td><h:outputText value="Critério"
                class="componentePF label bold" /></td>
        <td><h:outputText value="Valor Numérico"
                class="componentePF label bold" /></td>
        <td><h:outputText value="Valor ou Impacto"
                class="componentePF label bold" /></td>
    </tr>

    <ui:repeat var="a" value="#{topsisBean.avaliaProjetosPD}">
        <tr>
            <td><h:outputText value="#{a.criterio.nomeCriterio}"
                    class="componentePF label" /></td>

            <td><p:selectBooleanCheckbox /></td>

            <td><p:selectOneMenu converter="generic" value="#{a.escala}"
                    class="componentePF text">
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolha um Impacto de Escala"
                        itemDisabled="true" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{topsisBean.escalas}" var="e"
                        itemLabel="#{e.impactoEscala}" itemValue="#{e}"
                        converter="generic" />
                </p:selectOneMenu></td>
        </tr>
    </ui:repeat>
</table>
```

#### POJO

```
@Entity
@Table(name="avaliaprojeto", schema="somore")
public class AvaliaProjeto implements Serializable, SampleEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int idAvaliaProjeto;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idProjeto")
    private Projeto projeto;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idCriterio")
    private Criterio criterio;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="idEscala")
    private Escala escala;

    double valorCriterio;
//gets sets equals e hash
}
```

#### Print

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Alguém com alguma ideia de qual foi o problema?

Answer (score 1):

Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça, pesquisei no stackoverflow em inglês e descobri que a  tem problemas com componentes aninhados para coleta de dados. Sendo só para apresentação funciona bem.

Substitui por datatable.